# three.js - object not an instance of THREE.Object3D

Tags: three.js, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, commonjs

I am trying to use three.js [OBJLoader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-obj-loader) - [(docs)](https://threejs.org/docs/#Examples/Loaders/OBJLoader) with [vue-threejs](https://github.com/fritx/vue-threejs) and Webpack.

```
var OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader')
OBJLoader(THREE)
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader()

loader.load( require('./sphere.obj'), function ( geometry ) {
    var material =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } )
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
    return mesh
})
```

However this doesn't work. I have tried delaying mesh creation as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147002/three-object3d-add-object-not-an-instance-of-three-object3d) and using webpack [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader). Still getting that error.

Comment: Answered via github by repo owner: https://github.com/fritx/vue-threejs/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to [fritx](https://github.com/fritx) for this answer pasted
>   here from: https://github.com/fritx/vue-threejs/issues/2

Thanks for using the library!

For now, an  component supposes that the mesh exists when it is created, like `<object3d :obj="mesh"></object3d>`.

If you're using async loaders, your code might look like this:

```
<template>
  <object3d v-if="mesh" :obj="mesh"></object3d>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mesh: null // <----
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createBox () {
      objLoader.load(xxx, geometry => {
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        this.mesh = mesh // <----
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

More snippets by key word `user:fritx "Loader.load(":`

(including code in both vue-threejs and react-threejs)

https://github.com/search?q=user%3Afritx+%22Loader%28%29.load%28%22&ref=opensearch&type=Code

In "ExSpaceFighter.js", I also had a snippet with MTLLoader and OBJLoader:

https://github.com/fritx/react-threejs/blob/6e2317d1e616ed5562f889de6b885deffb14d18a/example/ExSpaceFighter.js#L18-L31

Hope that helps.

```
var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'SpaceFighter03/' )
mtlLoader.setPath( 'SpaceFighter03/' )
mtlLoader.load( 'SpaceFighter03.mtl', ( materials ) => {
  materials.preload();
  var objLoader = new OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
  objLoader.setPath( 'SpaceFighter03/' )
  objLoader.load( 'SpaceFighter03.obj', ( group ) => {
    const body = group.children[0]
    body.material.color.set(0xffffff)
    this.setState({ body })
  })
})
```

If I'm wrong, please let me know ;)